# Java Constants Instantiating by building a string

Tags: java, string, dynamic, constants

I am trying to read from a constants file the key value pair. It works when I directly use the class name and the field name, but does not work when I dynamically construct the Class+field combination. How to negotiate this issue?

The following is my Constants file

```
Public interface Constants
{
String  DEV_SELECT_STATEMENT  =  “DEV_INT_SQL_SELECT_STATEMENT”
String  INT_SELECT_STATEMENT  =  “DEV_INT_SQL_SELECT_STATEMENT”
}
```

Query.properties file

```
DEV_INT_SQL_SELECT_STATEMENT =  “SELECT * FROM SOME TABLE”;
```

JAVA class file     //This works

```
public someClass
{
public someMethod()  //This works
     {
      String sqlStatement = QueryLoader.getStatement(Constants.DEV_SELECT_STATEMENT);
      System.out.println("The  key is :" + Constants. DEV_SELECT_STATEMENT);
      System.out.println(“SqlStatement is : “ + sqlStatement);
      }
}
```

The key is : DEV_INT_SQL_SELECT_STATEMENT

SqlStatement is  : SELECT * FROM SOME TABLE

```
 public someClass  //This does not work
 {
public someMethod(String env)  //This does not work
     {
      String queryKey =  “Constants” +env + “_SELECT_STATEMENT “;
      System.out.println(“The Key is :  “ + queryKey);
      String sqlStatement = QueryLoader.getStatement(queryKey);
      System.out.println(“SqlStatement is : “ + sqlStatement);
     }
```

The Key is :Constants.DEV_SELECT_STATEMENT  //This does not give the value but a string

SqlStatement is  : null

Comment: You're trying to build and evaluate Java code at runtime; doable, but not the simplest approach.

Comment: @Dave, so what do we do to implement this. Suggestions/links would be helpful

Comment: Yes you can work around this as Dave says, but that's a horrible approach. Use a `Map<String, String>` instead, or maybe a Property file (which is a map anyhow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Reflection:

```
String fieldName = env+"_SELECT_STATEMENT";

String value = String.valueOf(Constants.class.getField(fieldName).get(null));
```

EDIT: I notice i had done some illegal things (Constants.class.getClass() is not valid)

Any how I have tested the edited code and it Works.

Comment: This code gives me an object. I do a toString on that object and try to use, but, this is giving me a NoSuchFieldException for some reason. The field certainly is there.

Answer (score 0):

yes..it will never work as inside the statement `String sqlStatement = QueryLoader.getStatement(queryKey);` the string value of querykey gets passed rather than the absolute value that you are looking for.

doing it is difficult although can be done.
what you need to do is, you need to override toString method and find a way to return the absolute value when toString on querykey gets called!!

Solution:
Use reflection!!

Comment: yes..just working out a way!! give me some time will come up with a solution!!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the solution is not to answer to the question that the OP is asking, but instead the simplest solution to solve their problem.

Yes you can use Reflection, but if I understand the problem correctly (though the question is quite confuse..), the basic problem you want to solve is to read `<Key, Value>` pairs from a file. The simplest solution is to use the right data structure for this, which is a `Map<String, String>`. Since you want to read the data from file, you don't even have to parse this yourself, there are java's [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

Comment: well, I do have the properties file. But to get to the key, I have to read a string from a constants file. This is necessary because, there are many queries common to multiple environment. In the constants file I have strings for each environment whose values are the same for different environment. Once I get the value, I go read the properties file which is of course a hash map.

Comment: @Raghu No I still don't see the reason there. You can easily use a HashMap whose key is a string `environment+real_key` that then maps to the specific value. You could improve upon that with a custom class that implements equals/hashcode so that you don't pass concat strings around, but same principle.

Answer (score 0):

You might use enumeration `enum`